# Pusher Chat Example Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, chat, nomethoderror

I am trying to work with tarnfeld's [PusharChat-Rails](https://github.com/tarnfeld/PusherChat-Rails)

I downloaded the file, did the usual `bundle install` & `db:migrate`.

I changed the api key in PusherChat-Rails / app / views / layouts / application.html.erb

but I am getting this error

```
NoMethodError in Chat#view

Showing /Users/gkolan/work/PusherChat/app/views/chat/view.html.erb where line #22 raised:

undefined method `auto_link_urls' for #<#<Class:0x007fdddb772818>:0x007fdddb710230>

Extracted source (around line #22):

19:     <ul id="messages">
20:         <% @messages.each do |message| %>
21:             <% user = ChatUser.find(message.user_id) %>
22:             <li<% if user.id == @user.id %> class="you"<% end %>><strong><%= user.nickname %></strong> said:<br><%= auto_link_urls(message.message, { :target => "_blank" }) %></li>
23:         <% end %>
24:     </ul>
25:     <div id="message-overlay"></div>

Rails.root: /Users/gkolan/work/PusherChat
```

I think its a very simple error. Could you please help me solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `auto_link_urls` method has been deprecated for rails >= 3.1.0.

You may :

- modify your Gemfile to use 3.0.9
- add the [rails_autolink](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) gem to your Gemfile